# tuple to list issue: can't find where I have made mistakes

Tags: python

For file:

```
Year  Grade
2000  100
2002  95
2001  88
2012  99
2000  66
```

and so forth, I have created a function that would calculate the average of grade of each following year. However, what I found was that instead of getting a list at the very end, I am continuously getting a tuple.

I have to get a list instead of tuple to pass the assertion test.

```
 years, average_grades = [],[]
    d = {}

with open(file,'r') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        year, grade = (s.strip() for s in line.split(','))
        if year in d:
            d[year][0] += int(grade)
            d[year][1] += 1
        else:
            d[year] = [int(grade),1]

    for year, grades in d.items():
        years.append(int(year))
        average_grades.append(float(grades[0]) / grades[1])
    years, average_grades = zip(*sorted(zip(years, average_grades), key= lambda p: p[0]))

    return years, average_grades
```

This function actually gives me

Year,  Grade
2000,  83
2001,  88
2002,  95
2012,  99

Something similar to this. It gives me the average of each year. However, it should be in orderly fashion (according to years), so I have done the last step.

Should pass this:

years_answer = [i+2000 for i in range(0,5)]
    assert_equal(years, years_answer)

The error I am getting:

```
AssertionError: (2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006[62 chars]2017) != [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006[62 chars]2017]
```

Any suggestions in fixing such problems?

Comment: It's returning a `tuple` because you explicitly *return a tuple*, that's what `return years, average_grades` means... More importantly, what is the *output you need*? Is it ust `return [years, average_grades]`?

Comment: Are there any good way to return lists instead of tuples, while ensuring calculations to be true?

Comment: Huh? Again, I have no idea what output you want, but just going by your code, if you wanted to return a list you just need to `return [years, average_grades]`, note, that is a *list literal*. If you have just commas, that is a tuple...

Comment: Try.. `return list(years),list(average_grades)`. Note that *zip* always returns tuples. This makes sure `years` is `[2000,2001...]` instead of `(2000,2001,...)`

Comment: [years, average_grades] does give me list, but what again causes a problem is it doesn't go through calculations of average grades for every other element other than the first one, which is 2000.

Comment: 1. `return list(years),list(average_grades)` in place of `return years, average_grades` **OR** 2. Use `assert_equal(list(years), years_answer)` **OR** 3. Use `assert_equal(years, tuple(years_answer))` **OR** 4. Use `years_answer = (i+2000 for i in range(0,5))`. *Separately* I don't understand your statement `This function actually gives me:

Year, Grade 2000, 83 2001, 88 2002, 95 2012, 99`. As per the code and the error in OP function actually gives you `year=(2000,2001,2002...)` and `average_grades=(83,88,95...)`

Comment: Thank you so much. You should have actually made it as an answer.

Comment: @Jerald.IFF put in some explanation, so that we can understand the flow of the code better. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one of the following:-
 1. `return list(years),list(average_grades)` in place of `return years, average_grades`
 2. Use `assert_equal(list(years), years_answer)`
 3. Use `assert_equal(years, tuple(years_answer))`
 4. Use `years_answer = (i+2000 for i in range(0,5))`

Separately I don't understand your statement `This function actually gives me: Year, Grade 2000, 83 2001, 88 2002, 95 2012, 99`. As per the code and the error in OP function actually gives you `year=(2000,2001,2002...)` and `average_grades=(83,88,95...)`

**Let's understand**

```
years, average_grades = zip(*sorted(zip(years, average_grades), key= lambda p: p[0]))
```

First let us see what zip [does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Let us split the above statement into smaller steps...

```
years=[2001,2000,2002...]
average_grades=[88,83,95...]
it=zip(years, average_grades)
```

at the end of `it` is iterator on tuples.

```
   list(it)=[(2001,88), (2000,83),(2002,95)...]  #State of variable
```

after sorting..

```
st=sorted(it, key= lambda p: p[0])              #sorted returns a list
st=[(2000,83), (2001,88), (2002,95)...]         #State of variable
```

now re-zip the tuples..

```
ft=zip(*st)                                     #Note that zip takes only multiple arguments thus we need to splay the list using *
list(ft)=[(2000,2001,2002...),(83,88,95...)]    #State of variable
```

Now finally when you do...

```
years,average_grades=ft
years=(2000,2001,2002...)         #State of variable
average_grades=(83,88,95...)      #State of variable
```

At this point `years` and `average_grades` are tuples not lists.

Comment: Thank you for going through step by step. I am not familiar with python and didn't really know that zip results in tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the final line that `returns` `tuples`:

```
return years, average_grades
```

to one where they are explicitly converted to `lists`:

```
return list(years), list(average_grades)
```

This will work as `zip()` `returns` an `iterator` of **`tuples`** when what you want is `lists`. We know this from [`the documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip):

> zip(*iterables)
>
> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.